# Help with javascript and user control

Tags: javascript

I Have user comtrol with image button dynamically entered into the Page.
 I want to get his ID in jquery or javascript to enlarge the image, but it always  enlarge only the last image, this is the  code,
 Thanks in advance!

```
function moveover() {
    document.getElementById('<% = ImageButton1.ClientID %>').height = "360";
    document.getElementById('<% = ImageButton1.ClientID %>').width = "200";

}
function moveback() {
    document.getElementById('<% = ImageButton1.ClientID %>').height = "130";
    document.getElementById('<% = ImageButton1.ClientID %>').width = "100";
     }
```

this is the page

```
 foreach (DataRow p in ds.Tables["Products"].Rows)
    {
        ASP.product_control_ascx prod = new ASP.product_control_ascx();
        Panel1.Controls.Add(prod);
        prod.Old_price = p["Regular_price"].ToString();
        prod.new_price = p["Your_price"].ToString();
        prod.watch_pic = p["Product_imag"].ToString();
        prod.rr = "~/ProductPage.aspx?Select_prod=" + p["Product_id"].ToString(); ;
    }
```

Even if someone has a code increases picture nicely?

Comment: More information would be good, show the images, how they are displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this problem is to pass the client id of the image button to the function as shown below.

```
function moveover(imageButtonId) 
{
    document.getElementById(imageButtonId).height = "360";
    document.getElementById(imageButtonId).width = "200";
}
```

Comment: What should I write in the HTML?

Comment: On the page load of the user control. btn.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", string.format("moveover('{0}')", img.ClientId)).